# Azure Web apps are getting very slow

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure web app which is connected with my mobile app. some times my azure app is facing slowness. why azure app getting slow sometimes.
am getting this issue sometimes please check the image [image]

Comment: How can we know if we have no related information to diagnose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**502** means a **Gateway timeout**. The front-end of the azure web app infrastructure wasn't able to communicate with the process serving your application. This could be due to variety of reasons. The common reasons include

- application time-out
- deadlocks in application
- Application restarts

I would recommend you to enable the following logging to collect some data and investigate the same:

- **Web Server Logging** (use this to check the time_taken field)
- **Failed Request Tracing** (this will help you in determining which module is taking the time)
- **Detailed Error Messages** (This will provide the exact error)

[image: Diagnostic Logs]

There is another option to investigate your app. Browse to **Diagnose and solve problems** section for your app and refer to the instructions there. See the screenshot below:

[image]